# generating pdf from mysql with dynamic column width according to content length

Tags: mysql, fpdf

am using FPDF library to generate pdf files from the database, and am extending PDF_MySQL_Table class to autmatically arrange data to the table. but i have 17 columns to display..so it overlaps each other..how can i make it expand to fit the content???

here is  my code:

```
<?php
require('../fpdf/mysql_table.php');
require_once('../db/connect.php');


// Page header



class PDF extends PDF_MySQL_Table

{
function Header()
{
// Logo
 $this->Image('../fpdf/ccm_inner_logo.png',10,8,33); 
// Arial bold 15
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
// Move to the right
$this->Cell(30);
// Title
$this->Cell(120,15,'Member Information',1,0,'C');
// Line break
$this->Ln(20);
}   



}


$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
//First table: put all columns automatically
$pdf->Table("select * from  members");
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

any help???

Answer (score 0):

instead of cell you have to use multicell checkout this link
http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php might help you